# Multiple inner join returning wrong data

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this query

```
select * from task
inner JOIN ec_child AS child ON child.id = task.for 
inner join ec_family_member as mother ON task.for = mother.id
WHERE task.group_id = 'NEWBORNCHW' 
AND task.status = 'READY'  
AND task.code IN ('mother_followup', 'new_born_follow_up')
```

whenever I remove one of inner join I get data for mother_followup and new_born_follow_up from task table but if both inner join is present in query then I get data for new_born_follow_up from task table only, why is that why data I don't get data for mother_followup and new_born_follow_up from task table.

Thanks in advance!

fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qTEs3492Lgoo3VunB7bWem/0

Edit:

concept is

table_for_mother_and_child_ids.
id_for_mother_or_child
1
2

mother.
id | name
1 |  XYZ

child.
id | name
2  | details

Desired Output:

id |mother.name|child.name

my question is can we do inner join on tables that are not related, like is it necessary that first inner join with table has to have a relation with 3rd table on which 2nd inner join is made, or inner joins/joins can be on independent tables?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com ?

Comment: what if you used an `outer join` instead of an `inner join`

Comment: @forpas I dont have experience using fiddle but created this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qTEs3492Lgoo3VunB7bWem/0

Comment: The fiddle does not contain sample data. Use INSERT statements with sample data so we can test.

Comment: Like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/19 for all tables.

Comment: @forpas I have updated fiddle

Comment: if you saved that fiddle, please share it

Comment: @forpas updated/save

Comment: @blackHawk after you update/save the fiddle you must post the new link.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qTEs3492Lgoo3VunB7bWem/5

Comment: @blackHawk for the sample data in your fiddle there is no row in `ec_child` with an `id` that matches any of the values in the column `for` of `tasks`, so you get nothing.

Comment: @forpas due to large number of columns I removed most of columns and kept only some column, the concept is there are three tables one contains ids that exist in other two tables and that two tables has no relationship with each other, can you look at schema and suggest if inner join work that way? because if i remove one of inner join data comes but not when both inner join present, my question is, is it necessary to have relation between two inner join tables, because in my case there is no relation between tables on which inner join is happening

Comment: edited my question, fiddle for actual data schema is given

Comment: @forpas if i apply left join,it works fine, don't know why

Comment: Because a LEFT join does not filter out the non matching rows.